# Python label expression in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

ArcMap 10.1, Windows 7 64-bit Professional.

I cannot get the chloride value to label correctly.  The problem is with the "if [Chloride] > 0:" expression.  The label renders all values from "Chloride". When the Chloride field has a value of -99, the label expression should render the 'Cl_txt' field not the 'Chloride' field.

"Chloride" has a Long data type.  "Cl_text" is text.  I have tried "if long([Chloride]) > 0:". Using long, the entire label does not render for Chloride values > 0, but the -99 values render the Cl_txt value of "NR".  I have also tried converting with float([Chloride]) and get same results as using float.

The strange thing is that that DTW renders fine.  DTW_ft is float data type.

```
def FindLabel( [gisID], [DTW_ft], [dtw_txt], [feat_date], [aka_name], [Chloride], [Cl_txt]):
    L = "MISC-" + str( [gisID] ) + '\n'
    L += "DTW: "
    if  float([DTW_ft])  >  0:
        L += [DTW_ft]  + " ft"
    else:
        L += [dtw_txt]
    L += '\n'
    L += "Cl: "
    if [Chloride] > 0:
        L += [Chloride]
    else:
        L += [Cl_txt]
    L += '\n'
    L += [feat_date] 
    return L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, not to label all`-99` values with `[Chloride]` but with `[Cl_txt]` try below-
I assumed `[Chloride]` is `long` and `[Cl_txt]` is `string` datatype.

```
def FindLabel([Chloride], [Cl_txt]):
    if long([Chloride])==-99:
        L= [Cl_txt]
    else:
        L = str([Chloride])
    return L
```

See image-
[image]

Comment: I tried switching expressions already, but it did not help.  In addition, I think you meant:
' if long([Chloride]) == -99 :
    L += [Cl_txt]
  else:
    L += [Chloride]'

Thanks though.

Comment: Ah! try edited answer. Make sure python is selected and no extra space is present in the dialog box- if error persists then post the error message.

Comment: Could you attach dummy `shapefile`.

Comment: Sample shapefile downloadable from https://rthicks.egnyte.com/fl/5LoRJK6IGP

Link expires Nov. 25, 2015

Comment: Ok, your code and my original code finally works.  The issue was a corrupt map and having the thousands separator on the chloride field set.  I did have to use long([Chloride]).  Thanks for helping to troubleshoot.